# SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition - Installation failed

Tags: sql-server, windows, installation

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition (French) but when I'm loading the .iso and running the setup, an instant error window appears saying :

**This SQL Server setup media does not support the language of the OS, or does not have the SQL Server English-language version installation files. Use the matching language-specific SQL Server media; or install both the language specific MUI and change the format and system locales through the regional settings in the control panel**

My OS language is set on FR (French) and the SQL Server that I got is also a french version... Any idea about what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server requires some additional software before core installation. Check log in root folder while error window is active.
[**Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2012**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx)

[Local Language Versions in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210665.aspx):

> Localized versions of SQL Server are supported on localized operating systems with the corresponding language or on English-language versions of supported operating systems by using the Windows Multilingual User Interface Pack (MUI) settings. For more information, see [Configure Operating System to Support Localized Versions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210665.aspx#bk_configureos).
>
> Localized versions of SQL Server are supported on English-language versions of supported operating systems through the use of Windows Multilingual User Interface Pack (MUI) settings.
>
> ---
>
> However, you must verify certain operating system settings before installing a localized version of SQL Server on a server that is running an English-language operating system with a non-English MUI setting. You need to verify that the following operating system settings match the language of the localized SQL Server to be installed:
>
> - The operating system user interface setting
> - The operating system user locale setting
> - The system locale setting

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, all the software mentionned in the list you gave are installed on my computer.

Comment: @Traffy Any additional information in log? And btw did you change the system locale setting to FR?